# Recommendation on the record type required

Tags: android

I want to create an app for the android platform; the app consists of large records such as Author name(1000 authors) and author quote(50 quotes of each author). 
other than that there will be biography and photo of each author.
More authors will be added and more quotes will be added.
option of custom/user based list consisting of a the search word/string will be added.

Should I use the 2d array for the store the authors and quotes inside the code or should I save the data in the file and load it from there. What is the usual practice by professional programmers.

Thanks,

Target/Example app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lammar.quotes

Comment: I think your question should  be asked here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete This question is not allowed on Software Engineering. It would be closed very quickly. Please do not suggest that people take their questions to other sites if you do not fully understand the other site - it only leads to a poor experience when they follow advice and are met with down votes, close votes, and deleted questions (and, in some cases, automated question blocks).

Comment: Why @ThomasOwens? As far as I understood Software Engineering is for theoretical programming or algorithms, he is not looking for a specific code and he is more searching for an advice of how to do something in a more theoretical way of how I as a programmer will solve this? Can you clarify why would be out of topic? At this point, he doesn't even have a code to analyze.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete It's too broad - there is insufficient detail in the requirements to choose one option and it would become a list of possible options without good criteria for anyone to choose which one best meets the given requirements. Given the nature of the question, the right thing for user5653890 to do would be to build out one solution (perhaps the 2d array and saving to a file solution), profile it, and then ask questions about performance on an appropriate site (which maybe SO, Software Engineering, or Code Review, depending on the question specifics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice to develop such type of Android application.

Keep data on the server, which serves facility for future update content, Instead of keep changing the version of the application on PlayStore.

Cache some data with help of SQLite database or any other you know.

Instead of using 2D array , use model class to access data smoothly. You can use Collections from Java, which help you a lot. The model class allows you store multiple attributes of element/object.